# alt + = not working in Excel 2010 on my HP laptop

Tags: microsoft-excel

I was using MS Office 2010 on My Lenovo laptop and now I have purchased a new HP laptop, also with MS Office 2010.

I have a problem with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> keys not working for Auto-sum in Excel. All other key combinations are working well.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Start Excel in Safe Mode and check if the keyboard shortcut works then. If it does, one of the add-ins you have installed and activated is overriding the built-in shortcut.

To start Excel in Safe Mode, open the Start menu, find the Excel icon, hold down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and click the Excel icon. This will start Excel without any add-ins.

Check if the shortcut works now.

In that case,

- start Excel in normal mode
- disable all add-ins,
- then enable add-ins one by one
- Every time you enable an add-in, close Excel, open it again in normal mode
- then see if the keyboard shortcut works.

Once you have identified the add-in that takes over the keyboard shortcut, disable the add-in. If disabling is not an option, learn how to create an autosum by clicking the autosum icon on the ribbon instead of using the keyboard shortcut.

For more info about safe modes in Office, see [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Work-with-Office-safe-modes-dedf944a-5f4b-4afb-a453-528af4f7ac72)

Answer (score 2):

It's possible some other program has hijacked that shortcut key. To test it, drop this code into VBA:

```vb
Sub AssignOnKey()
    Application.OnKey "%=", "doMsg"
End Sub

Function doMsg()
    MsgBox "You pressed ALT + ="
    Application.OnKey "%="
End Function
```

Run the sub `AssignOnKey` and go back into Excel. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> and see if the message box pops up. If it does, then Excel has "seen" that keyboard input and you can proceed with [teylyn's suggestions](https://superuser.com/a/1032406/348859). If nothing pops up, then Excel did *not* "see" the input, most likely because some other program has a keyboard hook that's capturing it and not passing it on.

Answer (score 1):

So I was having the same problem, and then I switched the keyboard from "US" to a different keyboard (in my case Canadian Multiligual Standard but it could work with any other one I think), then I switched the keyboard back to "US", and now the function works. No idea how this fixed it, but I hope it works for you as well. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a simple mistake. Some keyboards have <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key on the right instead of the normal <kbd>Alt</kbd> key. <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> would not work in these cases and you'd have to use the **left** <kbd>Alt</kbd> key (normal <kbd>Alt</kbd> key) for Auto Sum.

Comment: This seems unlikely to be the answer, as the question says “All other key combinations are working well.”

Answer (score 0):

for fixing this problem, you just needed to change your keyboard English(United states).
thats all. your problem will get resolved